# Generate smoothing splines for one feature variable in R

Tags: r, spline, smoothing

After reading materials about smoothing splines, I want to use the following R code to generate the smoothing spline for the feature variable x.

Here is what I did to obtain the bases for the smoothing spline for the feature variable x:

```r
x = sort(rnorm(30)) # x is the feature variable 
px = stats::poly(x, degree = 3) # orthogonal polynomial basis

smooth_spline_basis1 = smooth.spline(x, px[,1],df=3, all.knots = TRUE)$y 
smooth_spline_basis2 = smooth.spline(x, px[,2],df=3, all.knots = TRUE)$y 
smooth_spline_basis3 = smooth.spline(x, px[,3],df=3, all.knots = TRUE)$y 

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(px[,1],smooth_spline_basis1, main = "smoothing_spline_basis1 VS polynomial_spline_basis1")
plot(px[,2],smooth_spline_basis2, main = "smoothing_spline_basis2 VS polynomial_spline_basis2")
plot(px[,3],smooth_spline_basis3, main = "smoothing_spline_basis3 VS polynomial_spline_basis3")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Does the thought process correct? Or am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The package `mgcv` gives you a nice spline smoother with the function `gam()` for generalized additive models. Here is an example where a spline is fitted to a sin-curve:

```
library(mgcv)

x <- seq(0, 2 * pi, length.out = 100)
y <- sin(x)

mod <- gam(y ~ s(x))
summary(mod)

plot(x, y)
lines(x, fitted(mod), col = "green", lwd = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: This is not was OP has asked for.

Comment: @eastclintw00d Thanks for the quick response. The package mgcv is nice but this poster is more looking for a smoothing spline representation of a feature variable over a fitting.